# iTunes Connect: "Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown"

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

My app was approved for the App Store yesterday and since then we have received dozens of reports of a crash that does not appear in development builds. But, when I go to iTunes Connect > Manage Your Apps > (App) > Current Version > View Details > Crash Reports, I get this message: `Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown`. This is true after I did a refresh, under every tab.

Given the number of emails I have received, there should be plenty of crash logs in there. What am I missing?

Comment: Exactly how many emails have you received and how long ago?

Comment: 20 emails since about 4am today (Monday April 1). I have around 5000 active users. I can reproduce the crash in the app store build on my devices, but not in the dev build from xcode, so I'd really like to see more crash logs.

Comment: It can take up to 24hrs for them to arrive symbolicate and appear in that area. But you will also find if there is few different ones it will filter out ones that aren't like the rest.

Comment: 24hrs ouch. Wish that was documented somewhere.

Comment: Yeah that's why I use my own system to store and symbolicate crash reports

Answer (score 8):

This is because of the way crash reports are send to iTunes, or mostly are not sent because the users don't allow these reports to be send to Apple.

Full description of what is going on, is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592723/474794

Short story: You should use a 3rd party crash reporting solution to send the data to your own server or a service. You cannot rely on iTunes Connect.